# Facing issues to scroll exact element and add data to div on window scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

There is 1 main section which is displaying and 4 empty sections which is display none. On scroll to bottom of the window it is working fine. When scroll to bottom it is add data to div and display block it one by one when you go to bottom. But I want to change it. If there is just main div and when user scroll reach to the main div then display the #flash-sale and again when user scroll reach to #flash-sale then display #men-category so same process for all div. My code is here on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amiralamkhan/ehLcr0x7/20/).

HTML

```
<div class="main" style="height:100px;background:#eee">Main</div>
<div style="height:100px;background:#eee;display:none" id="flash-sale"></div>
<div style="height:100px;background:#ccc;display:none" id="men-category"></div>
<div style="height:100px;background:#eee;display:none" id="women-category"></div>
<div style="height:100px;background:#ccc;display:none" id="all-products"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var pages = ["flash-sale","men-category","women-category","all-products"];
var count = 0;
var scrollFlag = true;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(scrollFlag && window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        var name = pages[count];
        count++;
        if(count >= pages.length) scrollFlag = false;
        $("#"+name).append(name).css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Editing the code and facing the issue here. When I am changing the code `$(window).scrollTop() >= target` then the scroll reach position is not correct on the main div and it is display all divs at one scroll.

```
var target = $(".main").offset().top;
var pages = ["flash-sale","men-category","women-category","all-products"];
var count = 0;
var scrollFlag = true;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(scrollFlag && $(window).scrollTop() >= target){
        var name = pages[count];
        count++;
        if(count >= pages.length) scrollFlag = false;
        $("#"+name).append(name).css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the issue and the new code is below. Also updated on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amiralamkhan/ehLcr0x7/20/)

```
var pages = ["flash-sale","men-category","women-category","all-products"];
var count = 0;
var scrollFlag = true;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(scrollFlag){
        if(count === 0){
            var target = $(".main").offset().top;
            var targetHeight = $(".main").outerHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            var target = $("#"+pages[count-1]).offset().top;
            var targetHeight = $("#"+pages[count-1]).outerHeight();
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() > target - targetHeight){
            var name = pages[count];
            count++;
            if(count >= pages.length) scrollFlag = false;
            $("#"+name).append(name).css("display","block");
        }
    }
});
```